# How do I properly tell the client it's not authorized AND show a login page?

Tags: http, authentication, http-status-code-403

So, I have a custom authentication system (I know what I'm doing). I'm getting what I think is an improper response pattern upon a user attempting to access a secure page though.

Basically, what I envision is this:

1. User access `/securepage`
2. 403 response is sent back along with somehow displaying a login screen

What currently is happening is this:

1. 302 redirect from `/securepage` to `/login`
2. 200 OK response sent from `/login`

What exactly is the proper way of handling this? My ideas so far:

- 302 redirect to login and then login replies with 403
- 403 error code with a server side transfer to login(this adds a ton of complexity though)
- It's correct enough as it is

What exactly is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

It's correct as it is.

403 means "Forbidden".

If anything, you would use a 401 "Unauthorized", but that requires that you also respond with a challenge, which you're not doing.

Since you're actually showing a login page, the redirect followed by the login page with a 200 is the correct behavior.

Comment: My only concern is google indexing my login page and such (yes, I know spiders.txt goes a long way, but still)

Comment: Web servers like IIS and Lotus Domino typically use the login form to display an "access denied" message to users who have already authenticated but aren't privileged enough to view the requested resource.  For initial logins, the space for this message/div is otherwise left empty.